# Start a depends_on docker only if it is not started

Tags: docker-compose

I have a service that runs in a docker. For *reasons* I want to run a suite of tests on it in parallel, for example integration tests and performance tests.

I have a docker-compose.yaml that looks like this:

```
# My service - the thing under test in this scenario
service: 
  ports: 
    - 4000:4000
  ...

# Integration tests
integration:
  depends_on:
    - service
  ...


# Performance tests
performance:
  depends_on:
    - service
  ...
```

I would like to continue to expose 4000 so that components outside of docker world can interact with it. However when I run these tests in parallel I get this error for one of the tests

> Cannot start service service ... 0.0.0.0:4000 failed: port is already in use.

This is because docker-compose is trying to start a service for each of the tests. Is it possible to tell docker-compose to use the same instance of service? Is there a better way to achieve the same results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this for myself and I'll document it here for anyone who faces a similar problem in the future.

Publishing ports from the service by default is the problem here. Depending on the context of how the service is started, the ports can be published or not. Better to use the docker subnet for communication between the docker containers.

The docker-compose.yaml would look more like this now:

```
service:
  # no ports declaration
  ...

integration:
  depends_on:
    - service
  environment:
    - SERVICE_URL=http://service:4000
  ...

performance:
  depends_on:
    - service
  environment:
    - SERVICE_URL=http://service:4000
  ...
```

Instead ports are published when needed with whatever starts the service:

```
docker-compose run -p 4000:4000 service
```